# Regex for optional first special character

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

Is it possible to create a regex for an optional first character?

My requirement is to create a regex which

- accepts alphabets and numbers
- Is between 6 and 100 characters
- only contain special character colon as the first character
- The colon : is an optional character

I have made `^([:][a-zA-Z0-9]{6,100}$)`

How can I make the first character : as optional? At the moment it is mandatory.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `?` quantifier that matches 1 or 0 occurrences:

```
^:?[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,100}$
  ^
```

However, if the `:` should be accounted for in the char count use

```
^(?=.{6,100}$):?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

**Details**:

- `^` - a start of the line anchor
- `(?=.{6,100}$)`  -  a positive lookahead requiring from 6 to 100 chars in the whole string (no more, no less)
- `:?` - an optional `:`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more letters/digits
- `$` - end of string.